# Graph algorithm advise: find all affected paths between two nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin, graph-theory

I'm looking if there is a known solution for the task I have in mind

**Given**: Undirected graph with V > 100k nodes. Most of the vertices have a degree of 1-2, but some of them might have up to 10-20k edges.
I'm interested in [all simple paths](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/allSimplePaths.html) between two vertices or all paths ending on the start verticle limited by `maxLength`. Path can't contain the visited nodes but might end on the start node.

**Goal**: Occasionally some graph's edges are updated in batch. I'd like to find out what routes between vertices of interest were updated. Ideally in the form of `Iterator` but `List` is fine too.

Effectively I'm looking for a reactive way to find out about the affected routes.

The implementation could be in any language but Java/Kotlin specific is more preferred :)

---

Any references/relevant information would be very appreciated.

*I wasn't sure if it's a question for CS StackExchange but it looks more relevant to SO.*

Comment: " Path can't contain the visited nodes"  What does this mean?

Comment: Best guess:  You want paths between two nodes that do not share any nodes except the start and end.

Comment: @ravenspoint that's correct, path should not contain any vertex more than one(except of the first/last one - it's an exception)

Answer (score 1):

To find paths between two nodes that do not share any nodes except the start and end.

- Run Dijskta to find shortest simple path between start, end
- Add large cost ( = largest integer for example ) to the in-edges of all nodes on shortest path, except start,end
- Repeat until no new path found with cost less than largest integer

To find out what routes between vertices of interest were updated.  This is trivial

```
 - Multimap of edges, keyed by route index
 - Vector of updated edges
 - Loop over updated edges
      - IF edge in multimap
           - print index of affected route
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I think there is a misunderstanding: single path must not contain the same vertex more than once, but multiple paths between two nodes can(and should)

Comment: I cannot make out what you mean!  Why not provide an example on a small graph

Comment: A path found by Dijsktra never contains the same vertex more than once.

Comment: fair, point. I'll sketch something and update the question

Comment: I see from the definition you included that a "simple" path is one that visits nodes on the path just one.  To repeat: Dijsktra does not generate paths that are NOT simple in this sense.